# MongoDB PHP extension is crashing apache macOS

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

macOS 10.13.1, PHP 7.1.11

Php and apache installed with homebrew. Everything works fine until I install the mongodb extension `brew install php71-mongodb`. When I restart apache, I get

> httpd not running, trying to start

The log output after a restart is

```
~ $ tail -n 2 /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log

[Mon Nov 27 16:23:53.128889 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 39529] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Mon Nov 27 16:23:53.175190 2017] [core:notice] [pid 39529] AH00060: seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

If I comment out the lines added in `ext-mongodb.ini` and restart, the error disappears. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I saw few issues like this previously, usually one working workaround could be compiling mongo extension yourself.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
$ cd mongo-php-driver
$ git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-mongodb-sasl=no
$ make all -j 5
$ sudo make install
```

check this issue:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/247

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already tried that but was running into a `configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>` error for `./configure --with-mongodb-sasl=no`. Any ideas how to deal with that?

Comment: can you try this ```$ brew install openssl
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
$ export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"``` and try to configure was described in this issue https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/363

Comment: also check this comment https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/247#issuecomment-267718753 looks like very common issue because of not having some headers required

Comment: Ok so I managed to get it to compile but I still have the same `SIGHUP` error